# Why is unwanted script appearing in webpage?

Tags: php, html

I have written a HTML and PHP code which should show a survey form and invite you to enter your email address and have a submit button for you to click. However, when I "run" the code, I get some gibberish which I wrote in my code, which I did not expect to appear on my survey form. The code that I have written is as follows:

```
            session_start();

            if (!empty($_POST['posted']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
            $folder = "surveys/" . strtolower($_POST['email']);

            // send path information to the session
            $_SESSION['folder'] = $folder;

            if(!file_exists($folder)) {
            // make the directory and then add the empty files
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
           }

            header("Location: 08_6.php");
           }
        else { ?>

      <html>
       <head>
         <title>Files and folders - Online Survey</title>
       </head>

       <body bgcolor="white"  text="black">

       <h2>Survey Form</h2>

       <p>Please enter your email address to start recording your comments</p>

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="posted" value="1">
            <p>Email address: <input type="text" name="email" size="45" /><br />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
       </body>
     </html>
   <?php }
```

What's happening is that I'm getting:

`session_start(); if (!empty($_POST['posted']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){...`

and whole bunch of other stuff appearing at the top of the webpage, which is certainly not what I want. Could one of you experts please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Will this comment be read if I told why?

Comment: Of course your comment will be read...I read all comments.

Comment: I see Jay has provided the solution, `another happy ending` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not included an opening `<?php` tag in your page.

Comment: hanging tags at the end of file are fine, even encouraged by some developers (no chance of extra (html) output at the end of the file)

Comment: The `<?php` isn't hanging. It switches back into PHP mode so the else can be closed with a `}`. (It is generally recommended to avoid explicit `?>` at the end of PHP files as it can trash includes before `header()` statements with whitespace).

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that - I just wanted to see where the OP's head was at.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether OP's extension is in fact `.php` and/or PHP's installed or not.

Comment: After this one, I've only 3 upvotes left for today. I better use them up wisely ;)

Comment: I see you and I have raised you @Fred-ii-

Comment: Ohhhh so now you raise me huh? lol - Just as long as I get to keep my shirt, I should be ok. @JayBlanchard